# Problem with no webview sound when running the Android screen recording function while using unity uniwebview

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, webview, uniwebview

The moment you open a webpage with uniwebview in Unity and turn on the Android screen recording function, the audio track disappears from the webview and there is no sound, as shown in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv93A.png)

There doesn't seem to be a way to fix it in unity